# Monitor specific key patterns in memcache server?

Tags: debugging, memcached

We have a namespacing convention to distinguish our memcache entries. I would like to monitor the `get` and `set` that happens to a certain namespace to track a bug.

I can monitor the entire memcache operations but I fear that it is going to be a huge data because its almost a significant subset of the DB data and the logs are going to run into GB's, so I need to filter only the namespace I am interested in.

I have a client side solution which is to decorate (or over-ride) memcache.get and memcache.set to print the arguments if the key matches our desired pattern.

However I feel it is better to do this in server side. Also there would be too many clients if I have collect this information from all nodes. Is there something that we could in the server side to get the same effect? Anything in memcached `debug` module that would help us?

Comment: Maybe you can use tcpdump to analyze the packet yourself. If you don't mind write some code, python dpkt is very convenient  to do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way at the moment. I see on github that they're working on such a feature, but currently it does not exist as far as i know.

What i use in this case is:

```
tcpdump -i lo -s 65535 -A -ttt port 11211| cut -c 9- | grep -i '^get\|set'
```

As alternative you can use a proxy tool to get such a output like mcrouter. https://github.com/facebook/mcrouter/wiki/Mcpiper